# Why do these identical lines of Markdown indent differently?

Tags: markdown

[image: Markdown input]
[image: HTML output]

The indentation *should* be

```
def consume
  [array]
end
```

But no matter what combination of tabs and spaces I use, I can't get it to even remotely line up. I'm reading the Markdown documentation back to front and have watched the entire Pluralsight Markdown course specifically to solve this issue and nothing seems to work. Indenting 8 spaces doesn't fix it, and kills the syntax highlighting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What parser are you using? Markdown is not an exact standard

Comment: @TFD Sorry, I didn't think to specify. I'm using the Markdown-Preview core package in the Atom editor.

Answer (score 1):

Not much of an answer, admittedly, but the only way to supply the screenshot as below. Your Markdown appears to be fine; your Markdown parser broken.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, looks like a bug with the parser. A possible title for a bug report might be: "Fenced code block nested in list only de-dents first line". In other words, the parser is failing to remove the indentation from all but the first line of the fenced code block. As that code block is nested in a list, the first level of indentation (the first tab on each line) should be removed from each line. It appears that the parser is only removing that indentation from the first line.